# How to unwrap a soap response

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have dumped a soap response (from a WSDL service) in a file and would like to fake the service in order to test my application. I was wondering how to unwrap the soap response and build the return object from my file.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Well I have already solved the problem by doing some xpath, regex, .... I really found this solution awful specially compared to what visual studio can do with a real web service. My idea was to just return a predefined response and let the WCF machinery to unwrap the soap response. I have to admit that I have no WCF knowledge (I have just look at what has been generated by the IDE). I am not planning to become a WCF expert but just being able to unit test a generated service.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you take a look at soapUI, which is a free, open source, cross platform web service (SOAP or REST) test utility.

http://www.soapui.org/

soapUI provides the ability to mock both the client and server side of the web service, so you should be able to construct the necessary test harness for the web service from your test file.